# Can't use required attribute in the asp.net vnext class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class-library

**Update:** Of course I tried to add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. It doesn't work.

Problem: I can't use `Required` attribute in asp.net vnext class library project.

Case:
1. Add asp.net vnext class library project with default settings.
2. Create class `Human` with string property `Name`.
3. Add `Required` attribute to the `Name`.
4. Get compilation error:

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Required' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Below is my project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": ""
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Runtime": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I can use `DataAnnotations` in asp.net vnext, but not in vnext class library. Why?

Comment: Why the down votes? this seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @downvoter, kindly mind to post the reason also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vNext web project has a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. This pulls in a big tree of dependencies, the data annotations are under the package `Microsoft.DataAnnotations`

Add a dependency for **Microsoft.DataAnnotations** to use the data contract attributes.

In your `project.json` file change

```
"dependencies": {
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": ""
},
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.DataAnnotations":  "1.0.0-beta1"
},
```

Replace 1.0.0-beta1 with whatever the current version number is. Visual studio will auto-complete it for you.

---

Why does `Microsoft.DataAnnotations` work and not `System.ComponentModel.Annotations`?

From a little investigation `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` contains two targets

- `aspnetcore50\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll`
- `contract\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll`

The `aspnetcore50` assembly is for the new Core CLR. It's contains the `Required` attribute and works for the Core CLR.

The `contract` assembly contains all the types but the methods are empty. It's like a dummy dependency that has to be fulfilled by the framework. This dummy assembly is used on .NET 4.5 which is why your project targeting both .NET 4.5 and the Core CLR can't find the `Required` attribute.

On the other hand the `Microsoft.DataAnnotations` package depends on `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` but also references the framework assembly `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` which actually provides the types when you run on .NET 4.5

I found this post interesting. It explains what these contract assemblies are towards the end of the post. http://alxandr.me/2014/07/20/the-problems-with-portable-class-libraries-and-the-road-to-solving-them/

Comment: My question is why does it work with Microsoft.DataAnnotations and not System.ComponentModel.Annotations?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it in the evening at home (I'm +3 GMT and don't have the VS 2015 at work).

Comment: Ok I expanded the answer to explain why System.ComponentModel.Annotations doesn't work yet Microsoft.DataAnnotations does.

Comment: I've got an exclamation mark near to the reference and can't use it http://screencast.com/t/RaaxXpFyCam. All my settings for vnext class library are default. Previously this means that I tried to use a dll with wrong .net framework, but I'm not sure for current situation. Did you just added `Microsoft.DataAnnotations` to vnext class library and everything goes as expected?

Comment: I partially figure out the problem with exclamation mark. KPM doesn't download any package to .kpm/packages. Now I must figure out why.

Comment: For possible future readers. I resolved package installation by using `kpm install` from cmd.